# Storing images and metadata with PyTables

Tags: python, image, numpy, metadata, pytables

I'm using PyTables to store some images as `Array` and `CArray` data types. For each of these images, I also want to store some basic metadata (e.g., [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data).

I can imagine a number of approaches to storing both of these data formats, ranging from storing the metadata with the `AttributeSet` class for each `Array`/`CArray` to using a `Table` for all of the metadata.

My question is: What is the best approach if I want to be able to **efficiently query and extract images from the ultimate hdf5 file** for processing? For example, I'd like to be able to extract images taken at certain times (12-3pm) and process that subset of the data and then insert copies into the database or replace the existing arrays.

Many thanks for the help.

Best,

Nick

[Edit (clarification): I'm currently processing these images as NumPy arrays, and I hope to preserve that functionality]

Comment: See here for tips and example: http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/data_preparation/hdf5/hdf5.html

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the PyTables docs suggest the following.

Create a table. Create one column for each piece of metadata you are interested in. If your images are the same size, and this is known at the time of table creation, create a column of arrays and store them there. If the image sizes vary, create a column with an unique identifier for each image (the functional equivalent of a filename), then create a new group and create one array/carray per image, named identically to the list in the aforementioned table.

The other option would have been to use a lightweight RDMS (sqlite even) to store the table, which would allow for easy querying/sorting/etc., but keep the actual image arrays in the h5 file.